# Publish to "Your Facebook Wall and your friends' home pages" with Facebook App?

Tags: graph, facebook, facebook-graph-api

So I'm developing a Facebook app using Flash and I figured out how to prompt a user before publishing something to his/her wall by calling javascript from Flash. I'm doing it like this:

```
FB.ui({ method: 'stream.publish' ...
```

and it works great. But when I do it like this I see **"Post to Your Wall"** in the publish box title. But if I check games like Farmville, I see **"Publish this story to your Facebook Wall and your friends' home pages?"**

Any idea how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

I could find an example of it in one of my apps but I can't find it in the documentation any more - I reckon it's due to deprecating REST API so you might need to find a new way to do it soon.

That's my call `Facebook.streamPublish(message, attachment, action_links, null, 'What you want to display, e.g. post to your and your friends' walls');` Where `null` is you can put another person's ID and it will be posted to their wall.